# Reducing $\frac{B!(C-B)!}{A!(B-A)!}$ where $A \le B \lt C$

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

I have three positive integers: $A \le B \lt C$

I want to reduce the expression $$\frac{B!(C-B)!}{A!(B-A)!}$$

This is always an integer, but I'm having trouble reducing out the fraction expression.

Comment: You could certainly rewrite this as $\binom{B}{A} (C - B)!$, which makes the fact it's an integer very clear. Beyond that, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @T.Bongers I'm looking for an expression of products without any division or fractions.

Comment: @machinaut But, T. Bongers didn't use any division or fractions. The answer is a product of integers.

Comment: I guess that's so!  I was unfamiliar with expressions of $\binom{B}{A}$ which didn't have any fractions in them (I was only familiar with the fraction of products or factorials).  Wikipedia has a construction which is additive and recursive, which satisfies my original question!